# Using CTX with discord.py slash commands always results in "The Application did not respond" message in discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

For me, formatting a discord.py slash command in this way using CTX (not discord.Interaction):

```
@bot.tree.command(name="a_command", description="a command")
async def a_command(ctx):
     #body of command
```

always *works*, but results in discord sending the message "The application did not respond" when the command is run (regardless of whether or not any embeds/messages are sent using ctx.channel.send).

PLEASE NOTE that this *does not* occur when using @bot.command. I'm aware that if no response is sent, discord will say that "the application did not respond"

It never happens when I use discord.Interaction, so does it have to do specifically with CTX? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of your application command is always [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?#interaction). `ctx` works in this case because it understands `ctx` as `discord.Interaction` and both have the attribute `channel`. Hence, `channel.send()` still works.

By using `channel.send`, there's no [response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?#interactionresponse).

```
@bot.tree.command(name="a_command", description="a command")
async def a_command(interaction):
     await interaction.response.send_message("Hello World")
```

Comment: Is there a way to send an interaction response while keeping ctx?

Comment: Why would you want `ctx`? `Interaction` has more or less the same attributes. @JerryWill